# keep value of array php

Tags: php, arrays

I print this array with `print_r($formatted_meta['raw'] = $display_values);` and I get this output.

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [key] => wccf_pf_provamulti
    [label] => SCEGLI COME 
    VUOI CHE TI VENGA CONSEGNATO L'ARTICOLO
    [value] => L'articolo ti arriverà 
    già confezionato
    )
[1] => Array (
    [key] => wccf_pf_incisione_gratuita_matriminio_fedi
    [label] => INCISIONE GRATUITA ? 
    COSA INCIDERE
    [value] => lklklkkl
    )
[2] => Array (
    [key] => wccf_pf_incisione_opzionale_pagamento_checkbox
    [label] => INCISIONE 
    OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO
    [value] => INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA 
    INCIDERE (+€50.00)
    )
[3] => Array (
    [key] => wccf_pf_incisione_opzionale_pagamento_textarea
    [label] => INSERISCI LA TUA INCISIONE (Max 25 Caratteri)
    [value] => lkklkkl
    )
)
```

I need to keep only the value because I want to replace it with a custom one.

```
INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00)
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm trying to use this code :

```
$filterArray = array_filter($formatted_meta['raw'] = $display_values, 
function ($var) {
return (strpos($var['value'], 'INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA 
INCIDERE (+€50.00)') !== false);
});
echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
// Output the filtered array
print_r($filterArray);
```

I would this output in string (taken from the array)

```
INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00)
```

and replace this with custom one

```
MY CUSTOM ONE
```

Comment: `array_filter()` ?

Comment: what are the arguments inside () ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I try this, but not works : $filterArray = array_filter($formatted_meta['raw'] = $display_values, function ($var) {
    return (strpos($var, 'INCISIONE OPZIONALE') === false);
});

// Output the filtered array
print_r($filterArray);

Comment: change `===` to `!==`. it should return correct item

Comment: ok, I change the cose as you tell me, it print all array as above and not only the string $filterArray = array_filter($formatted_meta['raw'] = $display_values, function ($var) {
    return (strpos($var, 'INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00)') !== false);
});

Comment: `strpos($var, 'INCISIONE` => `strpos($var['value'], 'INCISIONE`

Comment: ok, works! it print also Array ( [2] => Array ( [key] => wccf_pf_incisione_opzionale_pagamento_checkbox [label] => INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO [value] => INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00) ) ) Now how I keep only this ? INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00)

Comment: `strpos($var['value'], 'INCISIONE  OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00)'`

Comment: If I put all INCISIONE OPZIONALE A PAGAMENTO ? COSA INCIDERE (+€50.00) I get an empty array. I have update the code.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the desired output?

Comment: You target string in the array contains line break . Use part before or after in the template

Comment: I update the code